# Importing QGIS layer to SpatiaLite table

Tags: python, spatialite, import, oracle-spatial

I have a Spatialite database with a table called `spatialite_objects`, with spatial and non-spatial data.

Another layer is an Oracle Spatial Layer (id, geom) with 2 table joins (based on 2 csv files) called `oracle_objects`.

I use the DB Manager to import this layer to my Spatialite database, successfully.

Now, I want to do this with a QGIS Plugin using Python.

I know to create tables and doing queries with the pyspatialite library (`from pyspatialite import dbapi2 as db`). I think about to query the Oracle layer and to fill up the Spatialite table.

Is this the same way the DB Manager does the import or are there more "direct" commands to import a layer from the Canvas directly to a Spatialite database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically use [ogr](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/) python module to import additional spatial tables into sqlite db.  A web search on this topic should bring up some examples of how to do this.  I'm sure there are other methods out there too.